# Easiest way to block access to a site for a group

Tags: permissions, restricted-access

I'm looking to remove access to select sites in our Sharepoint intranet for a group of users in a division we're divesting. I have a "M365" type dynamic group which should include all those employees. I don't see a "deny access" permission level I can use so am wondering if there's another way without resorting to conditional access policies (which don't seem to work).

Answer (score 1):

You wouldn't "deny" access as such, you simply wouldn't grant those users permissions to the site. If you've granted permissions to the site via a group that contains those users, then you'll either need to remove the users from that group or use a different group to grant access that doesn't contain those users.

Comment: We're tied to Azure AD and the "everyone" token includes all employees so I suppose I could create a dynamic group excluding those tied to the business unit being divested. It affects about 2k users so can't do anything manual.

Comment: There's no choice. SharePoint vs File System are 2 different things when it comes to permission management, it's by design. In File System you can "deny", not with SharePoint.